# How to Cut Out a Path from a Shape?

Tags: inkscape, path, transparency

I'm working with this truck vector and I'd like to convert all of the white lines in the large middle portion to transparency, as if I were erasing from the main shape. Is there a way to easily do this?

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

[image: The truck]

Comment: it depends how you drew it if they are shapes with white outline then no easy way, just draw the shapes

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know how to use [Boolean path operations](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/tutorials/advanced/tutorial-advanced.html)?

Answer (score 1):

[image]select one object  and then shift select 2nd object, then path> difference. If they are lines over a shape then convert the stroke to path then edit same as the example below [image]

Comment: I would first union all the converted strokes, so one Difference would be enough.